# Glide RequestListener not working

Tags: android, android-glide

`Glide RequestListener` is not working.(I am using it in a `recycler view` to save the image after it is downloaded). Here is the relevant code.

```
public class GlideImageView extends ImageView {
public void setImageURI(String uri) {
        setImageUri(uri);
    }

    private <T> void setImageUri(T uri) {
        Context context = getContext();

        if (uri != null) {
            DrawableTypeRequest<T> request = Glide.with(context)
                    .load(uri);

                request.asBitmap()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .listener(new RequestListener<T, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, T model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.e("Exception !!!" , e.getMessage());
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, T model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.e("I am working" , "regards request listener");
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {
                request.placeholder(placeHolderDrawable);
            }

            request.into(this);
        } else {
            Glide.clear(this);
            setImageDrawable(placeHolderDrawable);
        }
    }
}
```

I found out that in the GenericRequest class the `requestListener` is null in the method `onResourceReady(Resource<?> resource, R result)`.

The listener is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the uri is Correct.
You can check if the file exist like this

```
File fileCheck = new File(uri);
if(fileCheck.exist()){
//Your File is present at the uri
}
```

If u still have the issue it might be this [issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/618)

So try adding .override(w,h) to your glide